# How to update xml list in android every minute

Tags: android, listview

I am currently developing a android app which is generating a list. This list is generated from a php site which creates an xml file. this goes all very well and i am getting the results. But when the php site is updated the results in my android app ofcourse are not updated. can someone explain me how i let my android app automatically update the list say for every minute.

i've looked into alarm managers but i am not succesfull in refreshing my list automatically.

please help...

this is the code i have right now to generate the list:

---

```
package com.pxr.tutorial.xmltest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends ListActivity {

    private ServiceCount count;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        count = new ServiceCount((long) (1 * 60 * 1000), 1000); // 1 minute
        count.start();

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        String xml = XMLfunctions.getXML();
        Document doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(xml);
        int numResults = XMLfunctions.numResults(doc);

        if ((numResults <= 0)) {
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Geen resultaten gevonden",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }

        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("result");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nodes.item(i);
            map.put("id", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "id"));
            map.put("beschrijving", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "beschrijving"));
            map.put("type",  XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "type"));
            map.put("datum", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "datum"));
            mylist.add(map);
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.main,
                new String[] { "beschrijving", "type", "datum" }, new int[] {
                        R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle,
                        R.id.item_subtitle1 });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
        final ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv
                        .getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(Main.this,
                        "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private class ServiceCount extends CountDownTimer
    {
        public ServiceCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)
        {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish()
        {
            count = new ServiceCount((long) (1 * 60 * 1000), 1000); count.start(); //start timer another time
            mylist.clear();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            Log.d("timer", "" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a Timer: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html and set it again when the work is done. Also I'd use a service for this. BUT:

- This won't work when the device is in standby because network is
  down.
- If you force the device to wakeup it will kill the battery.

Are you sure you need to repeat the connection every minute?

I bet it'd be okay to refresh the data every 5-10 minutes if you enable the user to update data manually, just like google mail for example.

Comment: I believe gmail uses GCM or some other push notification and doesn't poll server every 5 minutes. I'm not sure though

Comment: The problem is that i cannot use a internet connection but i am using a local network. GCM is not a option. this app will function as a alrm trigger so 5-10 minutes will be to long... i know that this app will kill battery.

Comment: In this case I'd just use a timer.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't poll your server every minute. There's a solution to such a problem: [GCM](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html).

If you implement it on server, it'll tell all devices with your app, that data is updated and you can poll your server then. Or, if there isn't much data to download, even push your list with the GCM.

Comment: If there are lots of updates he will have to limit the gcm's on the server side, but this could be a good solution if you're experienced. Since he's asking how to repeat a thread I think he should start with a timer and a button to update manually.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The problem is that we cannot use any internet connection so gcm is not a option.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose I used Timer and [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

```
public class ServiceCount extends CountDownTimer
{
    public ServiceCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)
    {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish()
    {
        // update data
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
    {
        Log.d("timer", "" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }
}

ServiceCount count = new ServiceCount((long) (1 * 60 * 1000), 1000); // 1 minute
count.start();
```

Comment: thank you for your information. can you help me how to integrate your code with mine? i am very new with java and i am struggling to combine your code with mine.

Comment: Just: 1) Add ServiceCount class in separate file or make it private inner class in your activity class. 2) Declare `private ServiceCount count;` before onCreate(). 3) Initialize in onCreate(): `count = new ServiceCount((long) (1 * 60 * 1000), 1000);` then start timer: `count.start();`. 4) Make your adapter global. 5) In onFinish of ServiceCount call `count = new ServiceCount((long) (1 * 60 * 1000), 1000); count.start(); //start timer another time` 6) Also in onFinish `mylist.clear();` and update your data (fetch from server) and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`.

Comment: Don't forget call `count.cancel();` in onDestroy().

Comment: Thank you for your information... I am still strugglig with some problems. I have updated my code (see question above).

But it is still giving me errors (  mylist.clear(); and             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();) Is not correct.

I dont understand your part 4: Make your adapter global

and the last part i did not do correct:  6) Also in onFinish mylist.clear(); and update your data (fetch from server) and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Maybe you can help this nooooob

Comment: Make your adapter global means declare it before `onCreate();` and initialize only once in other cases you should use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` instead of `mylist.clear();` you can also use `mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();` also add `lv.invalidate();` after `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` and move fetching(parsing) of data in separate method. Now you don't parse data in onFinish() so your listView is empty. Make mylist also global. Parsing I mean all code from this line `String xml = XMLfunctions.getXML();` to this ... `getValue(e, "datum")); mylist.add(map); }`.